# Load url from CSS applied to element outside DOM

Tags: network, web-browser, dom, css, ssrf

I was wondering if it's possible to kick off a network call by manipulating the style tag on an element outside the DOM (which could lead to potential SSRF if this were done server-side). I've tried a number of ideas like setting `content: url(foo.jpg)` but nothing seems to load if it's outside the DOM. I've tried a number of cases with no luck, which makes me think this isn't possible, but I couldn't find anything in the [browser spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#url-processing) indicating that this couldn't be done.

Comment: Why would a browser evaluate styles for an element that is not being rendered? Nothing prohibits eager evaluation, but also nothing requires it.

Comment: Agreed, more just wondering if there's cases of eager evaluation or whether it's safe to add arbitrary style tags (user/attack supplied) to elements outside of the DOM server-side. I appreciate it feels fragile, more just trying to understand if there is a known exploit